# Script doesn't work when I try to launch it

Tags: autohotkey

I am using Autohotkey. I want to use <kbd>F1</kbd> key to start the script and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to stop it. I want the script to loop twice where the left mouse clicks once, waits 5 seconds, click the number <kbd>1</kbd> (above the letter <kbd>Q</kbd> on keyboard), wait 46 seconds and then left mouse click again. The following is my script but nothing happens when I click <kbd>F1</kbd>. The script is definitely active. Please advice. Thank you.

```
$F1::
Loop 2,
{
    Send {LButton}
    Sleep 5000
    1::Click;
    Sleep 46000
}
Esc::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$F1::
Loop, 2
{
    Click
    Sleep 5000
    Send {1}
    Sleep 46000
}
return
Esc::ExitApp
```

Comment: No it doesn't. The script doesn't even start.

Comment: @Trevor_zam It doesn't compile?

Comment: Re-tried it now. It compiles and runs from clicking the number 1. But it is not performing the mouse left click.

Comment: Same as before. It is not performing the left mouse click.

Comment: @Trevor_zam I just changed it again. It's working for me. You copied and pasted it, recompiled, and relaunched?

Comment: I just changed the LButton to Lbutton. It is working for me now. Thanks for help.